# Exporting Dygraph images

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have been trying to export my Dygraph images using the code:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript"
     src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="dygraph-extra.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graphdiv2"
    style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
"temp.csv", // path to CSV file
     {}          // options
    );
    var img = document.getElementById('demoimg')
    Dygraph.Export.asPNG(g2, demoimg);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The actual image on my aspx-page is OK, but when I right-click on the image and try to view it, it's bland. I have tried to change the parameters in var img and Dygraph.Export lines but heven't been successful. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The image space for the PNG image has not been created. If you add `<img id="demoimg" style="width:500px; height:300px;"/>`
after graphdiv2, the exported image will appear in that image space. When you right click on that, you will be able to view the image.